# 2017 Xamarin Cross Plaform App Searching a filename

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

How to write a program in 2017 Xamarin Cross Plaformthat can search specific file (ex: mysqldb.db3) and return the path.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As per SO guideline, you should show your code what you have tried. If you google this problem you can easily find the answers. This link might help you. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/

Answer (score 1):

"Cross Plaform" means code that runs on multiple systems with multiple differed idioms on how to access persistent data so you generally don't have an easy solution to "find file". You ether need to write platform-specific code that will **retrieve** this data or use some tooling like [PCLStorage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage) to **save and retrieve** data.
 
**Update 1:**
For android you can read what is [internal storage](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) to understand how you can and can not access it.
 And [Xamarin tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/#iOS_and_Android) on how to do it in xamarin.

Comment: I see. Let's be specific from android phone. path = This PC\Lenovo A6600a40\Internal storage\SQLiteDB